# How to install eclipse 4.3.1 on a gentoo linux system?

Tags: installation, eclipse, gentoo

Currently there is no ebuild for eclipse standard 4.3.1 so the installation has to be done manually. How is a clean installation of eclipse on a gentoo system possible? 
Is it sufficient to extract the tar.gz to `/usr/local/eclipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only properly available in binary form; if the version in the Portage tree is old, check the overlays.

As for a real proper build from source, [One Does Not Simply Compile Eclipse](http://thume.ca/2013/03/29/contributing-to-eclipse/).

Trust me, I'm a Gentoo Developer whom has tried to; though I heard recently someone over at Fedora managed to do it (though towards the user, I believe that yields just another binary), so, maybe we get to see it in the future on Gentoo if someone wants to spend even more time on it...

Answer (score 1):

If you download Eclipse directly from the site you get a self-contained Java archive installation. You can extract it and drop it right in your home folder if you like. Then you just click the eclipse executable to start it up. Sometimes I'll have multiple versions for different tasks (loading a single copy up with plugins can slow it down) in my home directory.

Just be aware that unless you put it in a place where the executable will be on your path you won't be able to execute it just by typing

```
eclipse
```

It might be considered more appropriate to distribute it across your system (e.g. the actual eclipse executable would go in the /bin directory or similar and other files would go elsewhere) but this would require some extra configuration on your end and I'm not sure what the standard way of doing it would be. This is more of concern if you're packaging it or sharing the system with a large number of people, though.

Additionally note that you won't automatically get the requirements installed this way. Fortunately, I believe the only requirements would be a graphical environment and java (probably openjdk is in your repos).

EDIT: On the subject of a "clean" install, this is pretty easy to remove - you just delete the original extracted directory and - if you want the configuration gone to - the .eclipse directory in your home and the .metadata directories in any workspaces. Deleting those isn't mandatory, of course.

Comment: In that case I would suggest `/usr/local/bin` for the eclipse binary. Not the /bin folder itself. (or /opt/ is you prefer that over /usr/local/ )

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with downloading it (without VM), extracting it and just starting it. From a portage perspective all you need to emerge is `icedtea-bin`.